# Trouble with using ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, webserver

I am trying to connect to a remove server (floating IP) using my local virtual machine (Ubuntu 20.04). I try to execute the following command

```
ssh -i keyname.pem ubuntu@XXX.XXX.XXX.XX
```

Where keyname.pem is a keypair (RSA) that I am supposed to use. But trying this results in

```
ubuntu@XXX.XXX.XXX.XX: permission denied (publickey)
```

The permissions for keyname.pem are 600, and I am in the same directory with them when trying to execute the command.

What could cause this problem?

Thanks a lot for help! :)

Comment: Your public key is not present on the remote server (check `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` there)

Comment: @Panki Can this be done from my local machine? I am not able to access the server (at least not with ssh)

Comment: If you can't login to the server (for example with password and `ssh`), you can't give yourself access.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have created the key pair, you need to transfer it to the remote machine so that it recognizes your end of the key pair. This requires that you have at least password-based access to the remote account

To do so, use

```
ssh-copy-id -i <identity file> ubuntu@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

If you don't have access to the remote account, you will need to provide the key to the administrator of the remote server and ask them to install it for you.

Comment: Should the keypair file be in which directory/folder? And should it be .pem or .txt for example?

Comment: There's usually no need for a specific extension. For example, my default key files are `id_ed25519` and `id_ed25519.pub`. Here, the `*.pub` file is the public one that can be copied to a remote server